# ConstraintValidation Not Working for a Rest Api Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I created an API and added an custom-annotation to validate the Request body object, but this was never getting called. Below is the Object. Please go through the code and help me out where the code need to be corrected?

**@NotNull, @Size is also not working**

**Request Body Object**

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Sample
public class SaleRequest {
    @NotNull
    private Integer sale;
    @NotNull
    private Date dateTime;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    private String customerId;
}
```

**Annotation**

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {SalesRequestValidator.class})
@Documented
public @interface Sample {
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };


    String message() default "Invalid Sale Request";
}
```

**Validator**

```
public class SalesRequestValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Sample, SaleRequest> {
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Sample constraintAnnotation) {
        this.message = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(SaleRequest sale, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        System.out.println("Tested!");
        return sale.getSale() > 0;
    }

}
```

**Api Implementation**

```
public interface SalesApi {
    @RequestMapping(
            value = {"/sales"},
            produces = {"application/json"},
            consumes = {"application/json"},
            method = {RequestMethod.POST}
    )
    ResponseEntity<Integer> submitSale(@RequestBody @Valid SaleRequest saleRequest);
  }
```

Could not figure where I went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Implementation looks ok.

Make sure you have set the `@Valid` annotation in your controller method where you expect to receive the request body of SaleRequest.

It should look something like this:
`addNewSaleRequest(@RequestBody @Valid SaleRequest saleRequest)`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying, API was implemented the way you suggested, but it isn't working, I added the api for review, Please re-check the question

Comment: Aaahhhh... I think I see what is the problem, please add `@Component` annotation to your SalesRequestValidator so Spring can pick it up when loading context

Comment: This is also working, the first thing I tried was that, I discovered even NotNull, Size aren't working

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend `@Target({ElementType.TYPE})` with ElementType.PARAMETER as you want to validate a method parameter with it.
A `@Validated` annotation is needed on the related Controller as well.